# What may cause apache slowing down

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd

I have a server setup with FreeBSD 8.2-STABLE running Apache/2.2.22.

Since this morning it became very slow. Connections are quickly established, but the response is very slow. This is valid even for regular files (not scripts) such as images, css and so on. I can't figure out, what could have happened since yesterday. I didn't change any configuration. The usage of `netstat` and `top` to make some profiling don't show anything unnormal - everything looks good. The system idles almost 100% of the time and the number of incoming connections is not so high.

What can I do to determine the reason for the slowing down?

Comment: Did you check for free space already? Try `df -h` to see if maybe your HDD is full. This might be caused by huge logfiles, etc. And it can slow down your server to the point of unavailability.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I've checked it - more than 60% is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is DNS resolution is turned off ? If not, then do it. Note, that you need to disable it also in your logformat, not just "HostnameLookups Off"
Check your logformat, or put your logging configuration here for further info.

Comment: brilliant!!! thank you very-very much!

Comment: You are very welcome